# ODE question related to Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0,$ then there exists $δ > 0$ and $L_0 > 0$ such that for all $x$,

$$|x − x_0| < δ ⇒ |f(x) − f(x_0)| ≤ L_0|x − x_0| .$$

By hypothesis $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ therefore is Locally Lipschitz Continuous, but i think I'm missing up something, can someone help me out ?

Comment: This is a local Lipschitz property anyway since you are restricting attention to a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Just take $L_0=|f'(x_0)|+1$  and apply defintion of derivative.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of derivative, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists, therefore it must be bounded. To elaborate a bit, there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f'(x_0)|\le 1$, hence $|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}|\le 1 + |f'(x_0)|$ by triangle inequality.

Comment: Could u explain me <=1 part ?

Comment: By the definition of limit, it could be any $\epsilon$, and I just picked $\epsilon=1$ for convenience.

Comment: oh thanks, understood now, but by triangle inequality shouldnt it be 1 - |f'(x0)| in your final part ?

Comment: No. I'm using $|a|-|b|\le |a-b|$.

Comment: Hey, i finished the proof, but im only wondering now why the less or equal in the final answer, shouldnt it be only less than ?